# how to align / display all columns in R using head() with the screen

Tags: r

In R, I did a `head(dataset, x)` where is `x` is some numbers.

The display of the columns truncate to next rows, instead of align in one rows.

How can I align every columns in a single row?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for the display width option.

You can see what it's presently set at using `getOption("width")`, and you can set the options by including something like `options(width = somebignumber)`, where you replace "somebignumber" with the width you would require to view the entire dataset without other columns wrapping below the data.

You can also explore the `View` function, which might be useful if you are more comfortable with a tabular spreadsheet-like layout.

---

Example:

```
> getOption("width")
[1] 80
> head(cbind(mtcars, mtcars), 2)
              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb mpg cyl disp
Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  21   6  160
Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  21   6  160
               hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4     110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
> options(width = 160)
> head(cbind(mtcars, mtcars), 2)
              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
>
```